# How to fix responsiveness issues on iPhone Safari

Tags: css

Any one help me how to fixed responsive on iphone safari browser ,issue on iphone 5s menu background color is taking white only on home page

https://priyachaudhary.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

Its because the same background code written here in **style-m.css**

```
.nav-sections { background: #f5f5f5; }
```

and in themes.css so make it !important in themes.css so may be it will work.

Comment: .nav-sections { background: #f5f5f5 !important; } taking color on desktop my issues only on iphone not in desktop

Comment: please see on iphone

Comment: use your desktop color .nav-sections { background: #222 !important; } 
OR you can use below jquery to call iphone and write your css in that code

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var isSafari = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Version\/[\d\.]+.*Safari/);
    var iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
    
    if (isSafari && iOS) {
//yourcode
    }
});

Comment: .nav-sections {
    background: white;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

Comment: its take black color on desktop meu please the menu

Comment: I have added another answer with script... use that script and call the class and apply color there. hope that will help

Comment: not working this script if i used mak os i can fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { var isSafari = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Version\/[\d\.]+.*Safari/); var iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream; if (isSafari && iOS) { $('.example').css('background-color', 'red'); } });
```